# Can't connect to OBDKey sometimes

Tags: android, bluetooth

I can't connect to OBDKey sometimes . I use BluetoothChat example to connect to OBDKey.
I can connect to it and read data, but sometimes socket is closed.

```
m = mmDevice.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] { int.class });

mmSocket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(mmDevice, 1);

mmSocket.connect();
```

Before this OBDKey is paired succesfully. Why does socket close sometimes?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have a valid `BluetoothSocket` before calling `connect()`.
Let me know directly if you need specific help with the OBDKey interface.